# Unable to install vue-onsenui due to peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, onsen-ui

I'm trying to install vue-onsenui using `npm install vue-onsenui --save` in my project folder. I get the following message but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried `npm install ansistyles` but that didn't work either.

```
npm install vue-onsenui --save
npm WARN vue-onsenui@2.4.3 requires a peer of vue@~2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN network.pack.app_user@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path /Users/BenFransen/code/pack-app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/BenFransen/code/pack-app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles' -> '/Users/BenFransen/code/pack-app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansistyles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 0):

The path in the error looks strange - have you added `npm` as a dependency of your project?

npm is generally installed globally and used via the command line - it's usually not needed as a dependency of your project unless you're programatically using npm in your project (is that the case?)

Try removing the `node_modules` directory (and possibly `package-lock.json`) and rerunning `npm install` in your project directory before adding `vue-onsenui` again - sometimes resetting things like that can help.

On a separate note, the peer dependencies warning is saying you need to have `vue` as a dependency in your project in order to use `vue-onsenui`, so make sure that is there as well.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've tried, but npm is locally and globally installed. Removing node_modules, package-lock.json en rerun npm install and after that npm install vue-onsenui --save result in the same error. Something must be wrong...

Comment: There is [issue 17444 on github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444)  that might be worth a look. Can you make sure there are no servers or editors running that might be locking files in your project directory? Then try `npm install` again.